# Opera Storage & Updating preferences

Tags: javascript, html, opera, opera-extension

I've been completely stumped for quite a while here. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have set several  menus with the IDs like so:

```
<li><label for="website">Select Website:</label>
        <select name="website" id="website" />
            <option value="http://www.site1.com">Website 1</option>
            <option value="http://www.site2.com">Website 2</option>
            <option value="http://www.site3.com">Website 3</option>
        </select>
    </li>
```

and with javascript like so:

```
    var sd = opera.contexts.speeddial;

    var weburl = document.getElementById( 'website' );

    weburl.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
        sd.url = this.value;
    }, false );

    if ( sd.url ) {
        weburl.value = sd.url;
    }
```

In an attempt to change the destination of the Opera Speed Dial's URL when one clicks on it. But it does not work. I have a feeling that I've got to add some js to the main index.html, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: Could you show the rest of the code, for example put your unfinished extension online somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to keep in mind what order the code will run in.. In the code above, the

`if ( sd.url ) {`

part runs immediately, but the code that sets sd.url will only run when you choose something in the SELECT element. Hence, when the if - part runs, sd.url will not be set yet.

Does that help?

Comment: AKA: you need to set the `weburl` inside of the change function.

Comment: Hm, reading you code again I see what you're trying to do. This answer did not make sense, sorry :-p